# Q (kdb): nested where query

Tags: sql, where-clause, kdb, inner-query

What are the ways to in `Q` to use the results of a nested query in a `where` clause?

I'm looking for something similar to `SQL` statement.

```
select from food where type_id in (
    select type_id from types where type_name = "fruit"
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select from food where type_id in (exec type_id from types where type_name like "fruit")
```

Your query was almost correct apart from what you passing to the *in* predicate and use the like function for string equality. You are passing a table when it only accepts a list. To send the query as a list I use *exec* which does the job.

Answer (score 6):

while that's the direct answer to your question, the best way do this is probably foreign keys:

```
q)types:([type_id:`apple`orange`cucumber]type_name:`fruit`fruit`vegetable)
q)food:([type_id:`types$`apple`orange`cucumber]price:3?2.)
q)meta food
c      | t f     a
-------| ---------
type_id| s types  
price  | f        
q)select from food where type_id.type_name=`fruit
type_id| price    
-------| ---------
apple  | 0.4593231
orange | 1.383906 
q)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it:

```
select from food where type_id in (select type_id from types where type_name like "fruit")[`type_id]
```